# Vue 2 API calls in one method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js

I have two api calls I am making in a Vue method. I need to be able to set the api results into two variables and then call them in another method for manipulation. How can this be done without using "Promise.all"

currently I have this but the variables log "undefined"

```
apiCall () {
    this.Loading = true;
    const resultOne = get('lots/path1', { locationId: '9047695746459876', fromDate: moment(this.dateRange[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), toDate: moment(this.dateRange[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result, 'result 2')
      });
    const resultTwo = get('lots/path2', { locationId: '897349823749237', fromDate: moment(this.dateRange[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), toDate: moment(this.dateRange[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result, 'result 2')
      });
      console.log(resultOne, resultTwo) //returning undefined
      this.Loading = false;
  },
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Promise.all`? It seems the right way to do it

Comment: I would expect those to output `Promise` objects, not `undefined`.  Is `get()` not returning a `Promise`?  How is `.then()` being appended to it then?

Comment: @David I'm guessing the results are `undefined` because the `then` function does not return.

Comment: @albjerto: But it's also not awaited, so it should be a `Promise` with an `undefined` result.

Comment: @perrotss no, not really. You can make use of closures to declare some variables outside of the `then` call, and when your promises resolve, you just store there your results. You can also do the same without `Promise.all` of course, but it just duplicates code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **async/await**.

**Edit:** In this case they will be called in a sequence, the second one will be made after the first one is resolved (this is useful only in cases when you need data from the first req to make the second req).
If you want to make them in the same time you will have to use `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()`.

Example:

```js
    async apiCall() {
        this.Loading = true;
        try {
          const resultOne = await get('lots/path1', { ... });
          console.log(resultOne);

          const resultTwo = await get('lots/path2', { ... });
          console.log(resultTwo);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } finally {
          this.Loading = false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: You're on the right path but this is not an answer to the question of OP I think. OP doesn't want to use Promises and preferes to create a 'callback hell'. So I guess the solution he wants is found here: http://callbackhell.com/